# Trying to implement Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 3 tables (`Tasks, Tags, Task_To_Tags`) in SQL Server

```
TASK
----
Id

TAGS
----
Id
Name

TASK_TO_TAGS
-----------
Id
TagId
TaskId
```

I have tried two different queries, and none of them return the correct results.

```
SELECT 
    Task.Id 
FROM 
    Task
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (Task_to_Tag
JOIN 
    Tags ON Tags.Id = Task_to_Tag.TagId
         AND Tags.Name = 'HT') ON Task_to_Tag.Id = Task.Id

SELECT
    task.Id 
FROM
    task
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
         s2t.* 
     FROM
         task_to_Tag AS s2t 
     INNER JOIN
         Tags t ON s2t.TagId = t.Id
     WHERE 
         t.Name = 'HT') AS s2Tags ON task.Id = s2Tags.TaskId
```

Problem: when multiple tags are associated with Task, either it return all Tasks with 1st query, and second doesn't return anything.

Task data:

```
123456
1234567
12345678
```

Tags data:

```
Id: 1 & Name: Test1
Id: 2 & Name: Test2
```

Task_To_Tags

```
Id: 1, TagId: 1, TaskId: 123456
Id: 2, TagId: 1, TaskId: 1234567
Id: 3, TagId: 1, TaskId: 12345678
```

Searching by Tag Name: Test1 should retrieve all Tasks (123456, 1234567 and 12345678)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. If you are trying to get a list of all linked tasks and tags, you might try the following:

`select tt.id, tt.tagid
from task_to_tag tt
join task t on t.id=tt.id
join tags on tags.t.id = tt.tagid`

I haven't tested this query, but if you were to provide a sqlfiddle environment with your three tables already created and with some test data, that would be the best way to get some help.

Comment: Your first query refers to a table `Task` whereas the second refers to `Tasks`; the first refers to `Task_to_Tag`, the second `tasks_to_Tag`; the first joins on `Task_to_Tag.Id = Task.Id`, the second on `tasks_to_Tag.TaskId = tasks.Id`... which is it?

Comment: Sorry, if it's not clear. I'm trying to get all the Tasks which matches a particular Tag. I copied this out from a giant database, and messed up some names, it's supposed to be Tasks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sample data and expected result will be helpful.. And which `rdbms` you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Tom Drake's comment above, here are two possible solutions. Which will work depends on the meaning of `TASK_TO_TAGS.ID`. If that identifies a record in TASK_TO_TAGS, try the second solution.

**Possible Solution #1**

```
SELECT TASK.ID
  FROM TASK INNER JOIN TASK_TO_TAGS
                    ON TASK.ID = TASK_TO_TAGS.ID
            INNER JOIN TAGS
                    ON TASK_TO_TAGS.TAGID = TAGS.ID
  WHERE TAGS.NAME = 'HT'
```

**Possible Solution #2**

```
SELECT TASK.ID
  FROM TASK INNER JOIN TASK_TO_TAGS
                    ON TASK.ID = TASK_TO_TAGS.STEPID
            INNER JOIN TAGS
                    ON TASK_TO_TAGS.TAGID = TAGS.ID
  WHERE TAGS.NAME = 'HT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for a join. You want the task IDs for the tag called 'Test1', so use an appropriate where clause:

```
select taskid
from task_to_tags
where tagid = (select id from tags where name = 'test1');
```

And in case you want to show some task details (e.g. a task description in the task table that you forgot to mention), then join the above with the task table or use it with `IN`:

```
select *
from task
where id in
(
  select taskid
  from task_to_tags
  where tagid = (select id from tags where name = 'test1')
);
```